# Error setting up Rails -- Could not find gem "actionview"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure why I'm running into this problem as i had previously set up Rails on my Mac successfully. However, I had to set it up again and ran into this error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'actionview' (= 4.2.1) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: actionview
```

I tried installing the actionview gem:

```
gem install actionview
```

Installation was successful, but I''m still getting the error messages above after running

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: You should be careful to ```sudo``` install any gems. You can cause a lot of access issues further down the line. You might want to look into resetting the permissions in your rails gem folder.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

do this:

```
$ gem install rails -v 4.2.0
```